# projectiles-kinematics

Tags: kinematics, velocity, projectile

Let's just say that I have two identical spheres at the same height. Both of them are given the same push (same velocity). One of the spheres is projected vertically upward and the other is projected horizontally. Which one of them will take the highest time to hit the ground? How can their kinetic energy be compared, with which the the spheres hit the floor? 
Can someone please explain these situations with kinematic equations?

Thanks.

Comment: Horizontal projection is like downward vertical displacement ... Now , can you compare time ?

Answer (score 0):

The sphere that is projected vertically first moves upwards, then downwards, whereas the sphere projected horizontally only moves downwards. Since acceleration is the same for both, the one moving horizontally must hit the ground first.

As for final kinetic energy from a kinematic viewpoint, symmetry requires that the velocities (and thus energy) be equal.